# Fetch Lumen controller result as Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue-router, lumen

I'm actually trying to build a SPA (single page application) with Lumen as PHP framework and Vue.js as Javascript framework. The reason I use Lumen is because I provide some API that are not available within the SPA. I'm using `vue-router` to route all my page within the SPA. My question here is: is this possible to call a Lumen controller and get the result (blade vue) into a component for Vue.js?

I've searched the entire web for some help about my issue but, since I am not very used to code with vue.js, I didn't found what I need.

Here's what my app.js look for the moment:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Foo = {
    template: '<div>foo</div>'
}
const Bar = {
    template: '<div><span>bar</span></div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/foo',
            component: Foo
        },
        {
            path: '/bar',
            component: Bar
        }
    ]
});

new Vue({router}).$mount('#app');
```

But actually, I really want something like that:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/foo',
            component: './user/' // Calling controller expo as GET method (default action would be index()) and retreiving the blade vue for the vue.js component
        },
        {
            path: '/bar',
            component: './expo/' // Calling controller expo as GET method (default action would be index()) and retreiving the blade vue for the vue.js component
        }
    ]
});

new Vue({router}).$mount('#app');
```

Thank you for your help. If you have any other solution for my problem, I'll be happy to hear them. I don't mind using other PHP framework or Javascript framework but, I this is possible with Lumen and Vue, I still wish to continue with them.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, you will have to do an ajax request to get the rendered blade view from Lumen. But then I wonder why you would use Vue router for this. You are loading an enormous amount of JavaScript just to load some pages over ajax.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is because I thought `vue-route` would be able to do the trick but, if you say I only need to call my page over ajax, I guess I would do it that way.